# New LAMP stack on virtual host. How to display site to the outside world?

Tags: server, apache2

I'm a new user.  Just installed my first LAMP stack and added some content on a virtual host.  Site displays well on localhost or the internal network IP address.  What are the next steps to be able to have the site displayed to the outside world?
I am a TWC residential customer and have bridged the TWC Arris modem, disabled the security and wireless connections. I have an Asus router connected to the TWC Arris modem.  DHCP is enabled at this time and I have not set a static IP address at this time. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's hardly an Ubuntu question, it's rather one to the Time Warner Cable support or user community.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu? This forum is for ubuntu-related questions only.

Comment: HI,Sorry i,m new to all of this. Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 server edition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter to you router/moden configuration web interface and enable and configure your computer in [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demilitarized_zone)

If your IP is static it is enough, but if you have dynamic IP you should also configure dynamic dns. To enable it depends your router brand and model. Maybe [this information](http://setuprouter.com/router/arris/tg852g/dns.htm) helps.